# Wordpress - Custom post type sort based on dropdown value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, dropdown, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make a dropdown with four different choices. When the user click on a choice I want the page load (without a submit button) the a specific category for the custom post type. On the first page load the first choise (beers (date)) should be loaded.

**My page template right know**

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div class="post-section container-fluid">

                <?php
                $args = array('post_type' => 'beers', 'cat'=>4, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC');
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                    $counter = 0;
                    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                        if ($counter % 4 == 0) :
                            echo $counter > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
                            echo "<div class='beer-section beer-group'>";
                        endif;
                ?>

                <div class="beer-col span_3_of_12 beer-box">
                    <?php
                        $attachment_id = get_field('beer_image');
                        $size = "large";
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="vertical-align">
                                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                <hr>
                                <p><?php the_field('beer_slogan'); ?></p>
                                <p><?php the_field('beer_abv'); ?></p>
                                <p><span class="icon-arrow-r"></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php
                    $counter++;
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The four choises the dropdown should have is:

**"Beers (Date)"** *- 'cat'=>4, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'*

**"Beers (A-Z)"** *- 'cat'=>4, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'*

**"Kegs (Date)"** *- 'cat'=>5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'*

**"Kegs (A-Z)"** *- 'cat'=>5, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'*

---

I know that it needs some form-code and if, else if statements but I can't get it to work. I'm very grateful for the help!

Comment: You could insert an HTML form (as you mentioned yourself) with index 0 to 3. In your PHP you generate an array with the four filters you posted above in the same order. So when your form-value is 0, you know user choosen "Beers (Date)". If it is 1 it is "Beers (A-Z)" and so on. Then you merge those filters to $args and it will work. A small Javascript "onchange" will help you with the auto-submit.

Without pasting an approach it looks like you just search one who will do it for you...

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer @lippoliv - I'm gonna try your solution :) No, I'm not just search for someone who will do my work. I want to learn how it works. Sorry if it was perceived as that.